# Need help installing a wifi driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I do know exactly what the problem is but I cannot find help that specifies how to find what exactly I need. Also, I have no previous experience with Linux or programming or coding of any sort so feel free to talk to me like a moron, I sure do feel like one right now.

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 onto my HP laptop which originally came with Windows 10, and of course the driver for my wi-fi adapter isn't compatible with Ubuntu. I need to know what terminal command will tell me what my adapter hardware is so I can find a driver to fit it. Using the `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` command I come up with

`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:81a2]`

After that I'll need to know how to download it to a usb drive (I'm on windows until I can figure this out) and what directory to move it to to install it on the hard drive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will give you/us the required information. Then it should be easy to give you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is not supported by the kernel because you installed 16.04, but not 16.04.3 on new hardware.

You can upgrade the kernel by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

You need to be connected to the internet to get the new kernel.

Comment: Would I be able to download 16.04.3 to a bootable usb? Or is it only possible the way you described? I can't get a wired connection with 16.04 either because I don't have an ethernet port and my usb-ethernet adapter only works on kernel 3. (I'll edit my question to reflect this)

Comment: The easiest way is to do a fresh install of 16.04.3. Otherwise you will need to download linux image and headers form the repositories and install them manually. It is long to explain. 16.04.2 is available to download from ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

Download the following on a computer with internet
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic_4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic_4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe/linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04_4.10.0.33.35_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-headers-4.10.0-33_4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1_all.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe/linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic_4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe/linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04_4.10.0.33.35_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe/linux-generic-hwe-16.04_4.10.0.33.35_amd64.deb
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164.1_all.deb
Transfer them to the Ubuntu desktop, then in terminal do

```
cd Desktop
```

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Reboot and then

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Then the Update Manager should update to the newest supported kernel